# FullCalendar Display wrong StartDateTime/EndDatetime adding double GMT value

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We are using FullCalendar.io library to our Salesforce LWC component. I am using timeZone = 'local'.

When returning the events from Server, browser inspector shows proper data, but when we open 'Fullcalendar'
it displays wrong time on client side. It doubles the GMT value.

E.g Event StartTime from server = 12:00 but when I convert it to GMT+1 it converts it to 14:00 instead of 13:00. Ideally it should only add 1 hour as per GMT+1, but it adds 2 hours.

For India Case where timezone = GMT+5:30, it adds 11 hours instead of 5:30. Please share your thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
@wire(fetchEvents)
    eventObj(value){
        this.eventOriginalData = value; //To use in refresh cache
 ///////
        const {data, error} = value;
        if(data){
        
            //format as fullcalendar event object

            let events = data.map(event => {
   
                var sttime = new Date(event.StartDateTime);
                var etime = new Date(event.EndDateTime);
                
                var formattedStartTime = sttime.toString();
                var formattedEndTime = etime.toString();
                
                return { id : event.Id, 
                        title : event.Subject, 
                        start : formattedStartTime,
                        end : formattedEndTime};
            });
            this.events = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(events));
            
            console.log(this.events);
            this.error = undefined;
 
            //load only on first wire call - 
            // if events are not rendered, try to remove this 'if' condition and add directly 
            if(! this.eventsRendered){
                //Add events to calendar
                const ele = this.template.querySelector("div.fullcalendarjs");
                $(ele).fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.events, true);
                this.eventsRendered = true;
            }
        }else if(error){
            this.events = [];
            this.error = 'No events are found';
        }
   }
```

event.StartDateTime = 2022-12-07T12:00:00.000+0000 (Comming from Salesforce)
event.EndDateTime = 2022-12-07T13:00:00.000+0000 (Comming from Salesforce)

My TimeZone from where I open fullCalendar is GMT +1.

Tried with many different config. e.g toUTCString(). but still either it displays Server Original Date, or it converts and adds GMT double value.

Comment: fullCalendar 4, or 3? Make your mind up...don't tag two entirely different versions. Also, no fullCalendar code is actually shown here, so it's unclear if the issue even relates to that, or just to some general JavaScript and datetime issue. Please ensure you've provided a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask], and [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Also please provide proper data, e.g. give the full exact values of `event.StartDateTime` and `event.EndDateTime` in the scenarios you're describing, rather than partial data. Details can be important. And also, what is your local timezone when you are viewing the calendar?

Comment: P.S. Fullcalendar accepts Date objects directly...there is no need to convert it using toString()

Comment: Hey @ADyson,
Thanks for dropping the comment and sorry for confusion. It's very first post here. Will try to enhance myself shortly. Look, I have edited the post. Added details about data coming from Salesforce and my local Timezone from where I open Calendar. So considering data from Server, which approach would be the best to convert it to Local time? I tried without toString(), but it does not convert at all, it shows Server original Time 00:00. It should show GMT +01:00. Thansk for help

Comment: Thanks! Andd when you say `I am using timeZone = 'local'.`...you mean you set the fullcalendar [timezone](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timezone) option, or something else? It wasn't 100% clear.

Comment: As an aside, `this.events = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(events));` is redundant. If you stringify something and immediately parse it back again, you end up with exactly what you started out with. `this.events = events;` should get you the exact same result.